# I am requesting a GET via ajax to express. But express doesn't receive the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, get

Here is my code.

**back end code (express)**

```
router.get('/principal/leave/approval/:id',function(req,res){
 console.log('requested');
 var approval;
  if(req.body.approve){
   approval=true;
  }else{
   approval=false;
  }
  leaveDB.update({_id:req.params.id},{approved:approval},function(err){
   if(err){
    console.log(err);
   }else{
    res.send('success');
  }
 });
});
```

**here is the front end**

```
<input type='button' value="Approve" id="Approve" class="btn<%=details._id%>"/>
<input type='button' value="Disapprove" id="Disapprove" class="btn<%=details._id%>"/>
</form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click',function(){
     var id=this.className.slice(4);
     $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:'/principal/leave/approval/'+id,
      data:{approval:this.id},
      success:function(data){
       alert('success');
      }
    });
   });

  });
</script>
```

when I run this I dont even see the "requested" printed in the console. Is there any fault in my code or should I use something else to make a request like this?
(I am using ejs as the view engine)

Comment: How is the `router` being setup for `.use()` by your Express `app`? If you check your browser's dev tools, does its Console or Network monitor show any issues with the request? Or, does jQuery itself report an `error`? – Side note: [GET requests shouldn't be expected to have a `req.body`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).

Comment: Since this is a GET request, what happens when you just go to the url from a browser?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (5ac61a68d89acf03f0379779?approve=Approve:88)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)

Comment: Also a GET seems like the wrong action to take.

Comment: @DilanSachinthaNayanajith so it has nothing to do with the Ajax request.... You are using jQuery slim which does not have ajax built in.

Comment: @Luca it says 'success'

Comment: @epascarello so what should I do?

Comment: Use a version of jQuery that has $.ajax support

Comment: ok...thanx everyone for helping me...I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I understood the fault in my code from the help of the contributors.
The fault was not with the code, but since I was using a version of jQuery that didn't support ajax, browser didn't understood the ajax request. Instead it showed 
***Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function***. So if anyone has the same problem better try your program with a `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your html layout.